# Temporary Managed Object IDs and child managed object contexts

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I am using a new feature in Lion, child managed object contexts for: "Managing discardable edits, such as in an inspector window or view."

When I pass a Managed Object ID from the parent MOC to the child MOC I will get a error if the parent MOC has never been saved: "Attempt to access an object not found in store."

```
NSManagedObjectContext *parentContext = [(NSPersistentDocument *)[[[self window] windowController] document] managedObjectContext];

self.subMOC = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType] autorelease];

[subMOC setParentContext:parentContext];

NSManagedObjectID *objectValueID = [[[self superview] valueForKey:@"objectValue"] objectID];

self.subObjectValue = [subMOC existingObjectWithID:objectValueID error:&err];
```

The above work well if the document has been saved. What are my options if it has not been saved?

Answer (score 3):

Before the MOC is saved any Object IDs are temporary, you must save the context to obtain a "real" object ID. I don't know any way around this.

Edit:

I mean, obviously you could do

```
if (parentContext.hasChanges) {
      [panrentContext save:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer, without requiring a save, is to use a fetch request. This code, which is very close to what is in the documentation, works for me:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:subMOC];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self == %@", [[self superview] valueForKey:@"objectValue"]];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

err = nil;
NSArray *array = [subMOC executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];
if (array != nil)
{
   self.subObjectValue = [array objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

In my project I still use the code from the question above and only use the fetch request if it fails.

Comment: It's not a thread safe approach, if it's worry you. You passes object itself here. Using managed object ID is safe. But, I'm stuck with same situation that you are:)